# How to add a wrapper function for setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a user registration form in React that updates the state when the username and password textfields' content changes, for example:

```js
<TextField onChange={e => this.updateUser(e)} />
```

```js
updateUser(
  evt: React.ChangeEvent<
    HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement
  >
) {
  const user = evt.target.value;
  this.setState({ user });
}
```

However, I would like to **generalize the `updateUser()` and `updatePassword()` functions** so that when I add more fields to the component I can call something like `updateField(e, "password")` rather than writing a new function to update every field in the state.

I've tried this:

```js
updateField(
  evt: React.ChangeEvent<
    HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement
  >,
  field: string
) {
  let updatedField = {};
  updatedField[field] = evt.target.value; // error here
  this.setState(updatedField);
}
```

the error I get is

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'
```

I am not doing this

```js
<TextField onChange={e => this.setState({user:e.target.value})} />
```

because my update functions actually do a little more than I pasted here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt is close. The problem you have is that a field key of `string` is too broad, it could be anything so the type-checker is not going to allow it to be used as a key of the state. What you want is to constrain the key to be a key of your state. Assuming you're in a `Component` where `MyState` is the state type argument, this should do the trick:

```
updateField<K extends keyof MyState>(
  event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>,
  field: K
) {
  const { value } = event.target;
  this.setState({
    [field]: value
  } as Pick<MyProps, K>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because when you declare this:

```
let updatedField = {};
```

the variable `updatedField` has for a type an empty object. Thus, when you try to set a property on it, TypeScript tells you that you cannot do it, because an empty object has by definition no property: *No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'*

A simple way to solve the problem would be to change your code to this:

```
updateField(
  evt: React.ChangeEvent<
    HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement
  >,
  field: string
) {
  this.setState({
    [field]: evt.target.value
  });
}
```

This immediately creates an object with a dynamic ["computed" property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) name (your field) and the value passed by the event, which is then given to `setState`.

**Edit:** As [Aaron Beall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225281/aaron-beall) said, TypeScript shows an error here because the computed property is not part of your state's type. You should refer to their answer

Comment: `setState` isn't going to accept that argument, though

Comment: You're absolutely right, I didn't remember how strict TypeScript was. I should've included the generic type.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a higher order function to generalize updating specific fields. Here is an example implementation:

```js
class ExampleForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: '',
    password: ''
  }
  
  setStateFromValue = prop => ({target:{value}}) => {
    this.setState({[prop]: value})
  }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <form>
        <input onChange={this.setStateFromValue('name')} />
        <input type="password" onChange={this.setStateFromValue('password')} />
        <div>
          State: {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ExampleForm />, document.querySelector("#form"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="form"></div>
```